# wrong variable values using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I am writing code to store secrets in secrets manager. Here is my code snippet:

```
for a in keys:
    title = a.title
    key = a.key
    secrets_manager_response = secrets_client.create_secret(
        Name = 'test',
        Description = 'Store',
        SecretString = '{"title":"key"}'
```

`title` and `key` gets stored as `SecretString` and not the actual values (`a.title, a.key`). How do I get the values stored in variables in `SecretString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your secret string is hardcoded to be openbrace, doublequote, t, i, t, l, e, doublequote, colon, doublequote, k, e, y, doublequote, closebrace.

```
'{"title":"key"}'
```

If you're using Python 3.6 or higher, you can use an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to inject variables into a string:

```
f'{{"{title}":"{key}"}}'
```

(The extra braces are because [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) uses braces to indicate injection points)

For lower versions, you can use string formatting:

```
'{{"{t}":"{k}"}}'.format(t=title, k=key)
```

Or, if the doubled braces really bug you, you could use string concatenation...

```
'{"' + title + '":"' + key + '"}'
```